# Registry monitor thread not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, registry, monitor

I have looked around for a registry monitor and the code I'm finding is this:
[Code here](http://pastebin.com/nKSXvZ55)
Which doesn't work, it says i have missing namespaces for: `ManagementEventWatcher`, `EventArrivedEventHandler`, `ManagementException` and `WqlEventQuery`.
How do i implement this class as a thread? thanks.

Comment: add this namespace System.Management. All your required classes are under this namespace. Go To project-->AddReference-->System.Management and add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this namespace System.Management. All your required classes are under this namespace. Go To project-->AddReference-->System.Management and add

Comment: Where it says "SELECT * FROM RegistryValueChangeEvent WHERE " + what do i put in?

Comment: No, in MonitorSample class RegistryMonitor, RegistryHive and EventHandler have missing namespaces

Comment: have you performed the steps i mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, i have added the reference System.Management and that got rid of most of the errors but RegistryMonitor, RegistryHive and EventHandler still have missing namespaces.

Comment: just move your mouse over the error and it will ask you to refactor. There will be option to add namespace. Add it from there.

Comment: I get generate new class and generate new type.

Comment: if not add these using Microsoft.Win32; using System;

Comment: post  your entire class so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Don't worry i have figured it out by my self, i will answer the question when i get time.